# Hot water periodically coming from undercounter water filter, but cold water still coming from faucet

Tags: plumbing

Periodically, usually in the winter months, hot water will come from my under counter water filter. When this happens I still get cold water from the sink faucet. It only happens occasionally, and running the water through the filter for does not seem to help, I just have to wait it out. It appears that the filter is supplied through the same line that supplies the cold water to the faucet.

*EDIT: Actually the water filter is connected to the line that supplies water to the fridge, which is separate from the cold water line that supplies water to the sink.*

Comment: Is there a heating vent in or around the counter? I have a (stupidly designed) bathroom vent like this: it comes out from toekick, but basically they just cut a hole and so the entire space under the cabinet gets hot. Until I get around to fixing it, we just don't keep mouthwash there (because hot mouthwash, as it turns out, is disgusting).

Comment: Nope, don't see any sort of vents around the plumbing.

Comment: The cold pipe feeding the filter could run alongside a heating or hot water pipe. If the plumbing for a dishwasher or washing machine is in the same cabinet as the filter, the whole cabinet could get quite warm and heat the water in the filter housing.

Comment: What type of filter system is it?  Can you define "*hot*", preferably in degrees? Does the filter system have a storage tank?

Comment: Where is this "hot" water coming out of , if not the sink faucet? Do you mean there's a separate coldwater feed that goes thru this filter?